# Bigquery.go export job slower than WebGUI

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, go, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509768/bigquery-go-export-job-much-slower-than-webgui)

I have now found that my 2 jobs take 2-4 seconds and 8-15 seconds respectively.

When I run my two jobs from the Bigquery.go client library they are done after 50-70 seconds. I use job.Wait() and have tried my own polling function (polling every 5 seconds) but there is not a noticeably change. Is this an issue in the client library, on the link level or my code?

Job 1 (DB Query, ~5s when checking by console)

```
job, err := database_query.Run(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

jobID := job.ID()
job, err = client.JobFromID(ctx, jobID)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

status, err := job.Wait(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Job 2 (~12s when checking by console)

```
job_extract, err := extractor.Run(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

status, err = job_extract.Wait(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
if status.Err() != nil {
    handler.Logger.Criticalf("Job failed with error %v", status.Err())
    return status.Err()
}
```

After this there is a simple return with code 200.

*I know that there is code which does not do anything which will be removed later.*

Comment: Try to create a simple runnable example and post that as Issue on the github's library issue tracker. It might be an implementation bug.

Comment: @Pentium10 How do I do that considering that I export data to GCS?

Comment: you can use public data for export, and you can leave GCS path as *edited*

Comment: Just a guess, but I wonder if the Go library is setting setting the default query priority to `batch` instead of `interactive`. Can you try explicitly setting the `QueryPriority` to Interactive and see if that helps? If you set it to `batch` in the WebUI, do the times then line up?https://sourcegraph.com/go/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/-/QueryPriority

Comment: @GrahamPolley The API at least specifically says that it sets them to interactive as default

https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/bigquery/v2#JobConfigurationQuery

Comment: I know. But maybe it's a bug. Can you test it?

Comment: @GrahamPolley Tried it today, no difference